# How to run multiple manage.py using docker file

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dockerfile, python-3.10

I have Django application which has docker file and using below command to bring up the application

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000", "--workers", "3", "--worker-class", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "myapplication.asgi:application"]
```

Would like to run one more process "task_process" which is present in the below directory structure

```
taskApp/
    __init__.py
    models.py
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            task_process.py
```

How to execute task_process after loading an application ?

I tried the below shell script commands in **startup.sh**. But no luck

```
#!/bin/sh
exec gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker myapplication.asgi:application &
exec python manage.py task_process

#!/bin/sh
exec gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker myapplication.asgi:application &
python manage.py task_process

#!/bin/sh
gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker myapplication.asgi:application &
python manage.py task_process

#!/bin/sh
gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker myapplication.asgi:application 
python manage.py task_process
```

Updated existing Docker file as below

```
RUN chmod +x startup.sh
CMD ["./startup.sh"]
```

Comment: Try adding `--daemon` flag to the last two attempts

Comment: Closing this. I found the solution myself and its working as expected!!

Comment: EDG356 : Found the solution able to execute by using below  #!/bin/sh
gunicorn --bind :8000 --workers 3 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker myapplication.asgi:application & python manage.py task_process